# create a queue using RxJS for incoming params and return data

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an outer module that is doing something and from time to time required loading an data by using callback:

```
const module = useModule(callback);


function callback(params:{id:number, takieLast:boolean}):Promise<any>;
```

This callback gets params and return data as a Promise. It is loading data from cache or through http call.

What I want to do is to create an queue to process and return data one call at a time. Otherwise many http calls are generated.
How can I do that using rxjs?

I tried

```
const queue = new Subject<{id:number, takieLast:boolean}>();
const moduleHandler = useModule((params) => {
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    queue.next(params);
    console.log('request for data');
    queue
        // .asObservable()
        .pipe(
            concatMap((xx) =>
                of(
                    requestToHttpAndCache(xx)
                ).pipe(delay(1000))
            )
        )
        .subscribe(
            {
                next: (result: any) => {
                    debugger;
                    resolve(result);
                },
                error: (err: Error) => {
                    debugger;
                },
            }
        );
});
```

});

It created multiple http calls for the same data. Can't think even with ChatGPT how to create such a queue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on the right track using `Subject` and `concatMap`, but I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do with useModule / callback.  Maybe showing you a basic queue implementation with plain RxJS will help point you in the right direction:

```js
const request$ = new Subject<{ id: number; takieLast: boolean; }>();

const response$ = request$.pipe(
  concatMap(params => requestToHttpAndCache(params))
);

response$.subscribe(
  response => /* handle response here */
);
```

Here we define two observable streams, one for the `request$` and one for the `response$`.  Whenever you want to make a request, just call `request$.next(...)` and pass the appropriate params.

To handle responses, simply subscribe to `response$`.

Due to the `concatMap`, requests are only executed one at a time.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76557110?devtoolsheight=80&file=index.ts) where you can see this behavior.